# Position fixed misturando margin

Tags: html, css, css3, posicionamento, margin

Quando eu defini meu header#cabecalho como position fixed, ele pegou o estilo(por exemplo o margin) da div.interface, eu não entendo pq isso acontece, quero que meu div.interface tenha margin-top:100px e meu header 0px

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

.postagem {
 background-color: white;
 margin: 0px;
}
#interface {
 width: 1200px;
 background-color: white;
 margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.cabecalho {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: green;
 padding: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
} 
.logo {
 margin: 0px;
 color: white;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 30pt;
 text-align: center;
}
.artigo {
 margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.titulo {
 font-family: arial;
 color: gray;
 margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px; 
 padding: 0px;
}
.paragrafo {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family: arial;
 text-align: justify;
 text-indent: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_css/estilo.css"/>
</head>
<body class="postagem">
  <header class="cabecalho">
   <h1 class="logo">TÍTULO DA PÁGINA<h1/>
  </header>
 <div id="interface">
  <article class="artigo">
   <h1 class="titulo">Filosofia Moderna</h1>
   <p class="paragrafo">
   Embora alguns autores considerem a Filosofia do Renascimento, nos séculos XV e XVI, como parte da Filosofia Moderna, em geral, aceita-se que o filósofo que iniciou a Filosofia Moderna tenha sido René Descartes, no século XVII, uma vez que seus trabalhos definiram e deram corpo ao escopo, objeto e métodos de tal período da filosofia. Da mesma forma, o trabalho de Ludwig Wittgenstein é considerado o término de tal período, iniciando o que é normalmente chamado de período pós-moderno. Este período não é caracterizado por uma escola ou doutrina especifica, mas por um estilo de trabalhar as questões filosóficas e por certas premissas ou hipóteses comuns.
   Embora alguns autores considerem a Filosofia do Renascimento, nos séculos XV e XVI, como parte da Filosofia Moderna, em geral, aceita-se que o filósofo que iniciou a Filosofia Moderna tenha sido René Descartes, no século XVII, uma vez que seus trabalhos definiram e deram corpo ao escopo, objeto e métodos de tal período da filosofia. Da mesma forma, o trabalho de Ludwig Wittgenstein é considerado o término de tal período, iniciando o que é normalmente chamado de período pós-moderno. Este período não é caracterizado por uma escola ou doutrina especifica, mas por um estilo de trabalhar as questões filosóficas e por certas premissas ou hipóteses comuns.
   Embora alguns autores considerem a Filosofia do Renascimento, nos séculos XV e XVI, como parte da Filosofia Moderna, em geral, aceita-se que o filósofo que iniciou a Filosofia Moderna tenha sido René Descartes, no século XVII, uma vez que seus trabalhos definiram e deram corpo ao escopo, objeto e métodos de tal período da filosofia. Da mesma forma, o trabalho de Ludwig Wittgenstein é considerado o término de tal período, iniciando o que é normalmente chamado de período pós-moderno. Este período não é caracterizado por uma escola ou doutrina especifica, mas por um estilo de trabalhar as questões filosóficas e por certas premissas ou hipóteses comuns.
   Embora alguns autores considerem a Filosofia do Renascimento, nos séculos XV e XVI, como parte da Filosofia Moderna, em geral, aceita-se que o filósofo que iniciou a Filosofia Moderna tenha sido René Descartes, no século XVII, uma vez que seus trabalhos definiram e deram corpo ao escopo, objeto e métodos de tal período da filosofia. Da mesma forma, o trabalho de Ludwig Wittgenstein é considerado o término de tal período, iniciando o que é normalmente chamado de período pós-moderno. Este período não é caracterizado por uma escola ou doutrina especifica, mas por um estilo de trabalhar as questões filosóficas e por certas premissas ou hipóteses comuns.
   Embora alguns autores considerem a Filosofia do Renascimento, nos séculos XV e XVI, como parte da Filosofia Moderna, em geral, aceita-se que o filósofo que iniciou a Filosofia Moderna tenha sido René Descartes, no século XVII, uma vez que seus trabalhos definiram e deram corpo ao escopo, objeto e métodos de tal período da filosofia. Da mesma forma, o trabalho de Ludwig Wittgenstein é considerado o término de tal período, iniciando o que é normalmente chamado de período pós-moderno. Este período não é caracterizado por uma escola ou doutrina especifica, mas por um estilo de trabalhar as questões filosóficas e por certas premissas ou hipóteses comuns.
   Embora alguns autores considerem a Filosofia do Renascimento, nos séculos XV e XVI, como parte da Filosofia Moderna, em geral, aceita-se que o filósofo que iniciou a Filosofia Moderna tenha sido René Descartes, no século XVII, uma vez que seus trabalhos definiram e deram corpo ao escopo, objeto e métodos de tal período da filosofia. Da mesma forma, o trabalho de Ludwig Wittgenstein é considerado o término de tal período, iniciando o que é normalmente chamado de período pós-moderno. Este período não é caracterizado por uma escola ou doutrina especifica, mas por um estilo de trabalhar as questões filosóficas e por certas premissas ou hipóteses comuns.
   </p>
  <article>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Marcos se possível edite sua pergunta e coloque também o HTML, sem ele não da para simular seu problema para poder te ajudar.

Comment: Usar margin para position fixed não vejo muito sentido. Se é fixo, vc posiciona com top, left, bottom, right...

Comment: sam, a minha intenção é deixar o título fixo, pra ele acompanhar a rolagem, não coloquei pq acho q n tem nada haver com o problema

Comment: Coloque um `margin-top: 100px;` e ajuste esse valor até que fique na posição desejada.

Comment: Não tem nada haver, quando eu coloco 100px os dois vão ficar distantes, o problema que falei lá encima é esse, eu não coloquei margin no título e ele tá pegando a margin da interface

Comment: Cara eu fiz um **EDIT** na minha resposta explicando pq o conteúdo fica sobreposto. É uma explicação simples, mas acho que vai te ajudar a entender o que aconteceu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem formas diferentes para vc ter esse mesmo resultado. Mas eu preferi colocar um `padding-top` no `body` pouco maior que a altura da barra verde *([o Bootstrap também faz dessa forma](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement))* e um coloquei um `top:0` no `.cabecalho`

Veja o exemplo como fica

```css
  @charset "UTF-8";

  body {
    padding-top: 60px; /* aqui vc define onde o conteúdo começa */
  }

.postagem {
 background-color: white;
 margin: 0px;
}
#interface {
 width: 1200px;
 background-color: white; 
 margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.cabecalho {
 position: fixed;
  top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: green;
 padding: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
} 
.logo {
 margin: 0px;
 color: white;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 30pt;
 text-align: center;
}
.artigo {
 margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.titulo {
 font-family: arial;
 color: gray;
 margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px; 
 padding: 0px;
}
.paragrafo {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family: arial;
 text-align: justify;
 text-indent: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body class="postagem">
  <header class="cabecalho">
   <h1 class="logo">TÍTULO DA PÁGINA</h1>
  </header>
 <div id="interface">
  <article class="artigo">
   <h1 class="titulo">Filosofia Moderna</h1>
   <p class="paragrafo">
   Embora alguns autores considerem a Filosofia do Renascimento, nos séculos XV e XVI, como parte da Filosofia Moderna, em geral, aceita-se que o filósofo que iniciou a Filosofia Moderna tenha sido René Descartes, no século XVII, uma vez que seus trabalhos definiram e deram corpo ao escopo, objeto e métodos de tal período da filosofia. Da mesma forma, o trabalho de Ludwig Wittgenstein é considerado o término de tal período, iniciando o que é normalmente chamado de período pós-moderno. Este período não é caracterizado por uma escola ou doutrina especifica, mas por um estilo de trabalhar as questões filosóficas e por certas premissas ou hipóteses comuns.
   Embora alguns autores considerem a Filosofia do Renascimento, nos séculos XV e XVI, como parte da Filosofia Moderna, em geral, aceita-se que o filósofo que iniciou a Filosofia Moderna tenha sido René Descartes, no século XVII, uma vez que seus trabalhos definiram e deram corpo ao escopo, objeto e métodos de tal período da filosofia. Da mesma forma, o trabalho de Ludwig Wittgenstein é considerado o término de tal período, iniciando o que é normalmente chamado de período pós-moderno. Este período não é caracterizado por uma escola ou doutrina especifica, mas por um estilo de trabalhar as questões filosóficas e por certas premissas ou hipóteses comuns.
   Embora alguns autores considerem a Filosofia do Renascimento, nos séculos XV e XVI, como parte da Filosofia Moderna, em geral, aceita-se que o filósofo que iniciou a Filosofia Moderna tenha sido René Descartes, no século XVII, uma vez que seus trabalhos definiram e deram corpo ao escopo, objeto e métodos de tal período da filosofia. Da mesma forma, o trabalho de Ludwig Wittgenstein é considerado o término de tal período, iniciando o que é normalmente chamado de período pós-moderno. Este período não é caracterizado por uma escola ou doutrina especifica, mas por um estilo de trabalhar as questões filosóficas e por certas premissas ou hipóteses comuns.
   Embora alguns autores considerem a Filosofia do Renascimento, nos séculos XV e XVI, como parte da Filosofia Moderna, em geral, aceita-se que o filósofo que iniciou a Filosofia Moderna tenha sido René Descartes, no século XVII, uma vez que seus trabalhos definiram e deram corpo ao escopo, objeto e métodos de tal período da filosofia. Da mesma forma, o trabalho de Ludwig Wittgenstein é considerado o término de tal período, iniciando o que é normalmente chamado de período pós-moderno. Este período não é caracterizado por uma escola ou doutrina especifica, mas por um estilo de trabalhar as questões filosóficas e por certas premissas ou hipóteses comuns.
   Embora alguns autores considerem a Filosofia do Renascimento, nos séculos XV e XVI, como parte da Filosofia Moderna, em geral, aceita-se que o filósofo que iniciou a Filosofia Moderna tenha sido René Descartes, no século XVII, uma vez que seus trabalhos definiram e deram corpo ao escopo, objeto e métodos de tal período da filosofia. Da mesma forma, o trabalho de Ludwig Wittgenstein é considerado o término de tal período, iniciando o que é normalmente chamado de período pós-moderno. Este período não é caracterizado por uma escola ou doutrina especifica, mas por um estilo de trabalhar as questões filosóficas e por certas premissas ou hipóteses comuns.
   Embora alguns autores considerem a Filosofia do Renascimento, nos séculos XV e XVI, como parte da Filosofia Moderna, em geral, aceita-se que o filósofo que iniciou a Filosofia Moderna tenha sido René Descartes, no século XVII, uma vez que seus trabalhos definiram e deram corpo ao escopo, objeto e métodos de tal período da filosofia. Da mesma forma, o trabalho de Ludwig Wittgenstein é considerado o término de tal período, iniciando o que é normalmente chamado de período pós-moderno. Este período não é caracterizado por uma escola ou doutrina especifica, mas por um estilo de trabalhar as questões filosóficas e por certas premissas ou hipóteses comuns.
   </p>
  <article>
 </div>
```

**EDIT:**

Explicação simples do problema com `position:fixed`: O que acontece é que quando vc coloca `position:fixed` em um elemento ele sai do "fluxo" do documento, e perde as referencia do lugar que ocupa relativo aos seus vizinhos, ficando relativo a página. Por isso o conteúdo que vem abaixo dele sobe e fica sobreposto. Vc pode ler a documentação da Mozilla sobre o assunto que vai te ajudar bastante acredito https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position

> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it
>   when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on
>   every page. This value always create a new stacking context.

Tradução do Google:

*"Não deixe espaço para o elemento. Em vez disso, posiciona-o em uma posição especificada em relação à viewport da tela e não o move quando rolada. Ao imprimir, posicione-o nessa posição fixa em todas as páginas. Esse valor sempre cria um novo contexto de empilhamento."*